# Which text object defines text enclosed in space?

Tags: cursor-motions, visual-mode, normal-mode

Since I need to operate on a sequence of symbols between spaces I'd like to know which text object defines it. Here is an example:

```
45908 Sep 24 21:31 [r].t3891993.tr some another text.
                            ^
                         cursor
```

In visual mode I'd like to mark `[r].t3891993.tr`, but simply typing `i<SPACE>` doesn't work. How to define such a text object?

UPD: That's not just about visual mode. In normal mode it would be very useful for me as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `WORD` text object.

From `:h WORD`:

> A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
>   space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.

This is signified by a capital "W". I.E. use `viW` to mark the text in visual mode.

In normal mode you could yank the text with `yiW`.

For more info see `:h iW` and `:h WORD`.